# How to change/extract the value of part of a manually defined datatype?

Tags: haskell, types, data-manipulation

Say I have the following datatype:

```
data MyType = Element1 (Maybe Int) | Element2 (Maybe Int)
instance1 = Element1 (Just 1)
instance2 = function(instance1)
```

What can I use in place of `function` with so that `instance2 = Element1 (Just 2)`?

Comment: You can not *manipulate* an object. All values are *immutable*. You can construct a new object, that is changed copy of the original one.

Comment: It is however not entirely clear what you want to do. What i it is an `Element2 Nothing`? Or an `Element1 (Just 3)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've edited the question to reflect the immutability of an object and to clarify my question.

Comment: You use [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You give three equations:

```
instance1 = Element1 (Just 1)
instance2 = function(instance1)
instance2 = Element1 (Just 2)
```

Let's use these equations to solve for `function`.

```
function (instance1) = instance2
function (Element1 (Just 1)) = instance2
function (Element1 (Just 1)) = Element1 (Just 2)
```

This final line:

```
function (Element1 (Just 1)) = Element1 (Just 2)
```

is a perfectly good chunk of Haskell code that defines a function named `function`. Of course, it doesn't say what to do with things that are actually `Element2`s, or that are `Element1`s containing `Nothing`s, or that are `Element1`s containing `Just`s containing things that aren't `1`! But it does meet the specification given by the three original equations, and I think is an excellent demonstration of the concept of "equational reasoning" that Haskell shares with mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

If you generlize your type slightly, you can make it a functor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data MyType a = Element1 (Maybe a) | Element2 (Maybe a) deriving (Functor, Show)
```

Then the function you are looking for is `(<$)`, from the `Functor` typeclass.

```
> i1 = Element1 (Just 1)
> i1
Element1 (Just 1)
> 2 <$ i1
Element1 (Just 2)
```

---

If you don't want to use the `DeriveFunctor` extension, the instance is  trivial to define manually.

```
instance Functor MyType where
    fmap f (Element1 x) = Element1 (fmap f x)
    fmap f (Element2 x) = Element2 (fmap f x)
```

---

A specialized version of `(<$)` for a monomorphic type might look like

```
data MyType = Element1 (Maybe Int) | Element2 (Maybe Int)

change :: Int -> MyType -> MyType
change new (Element1 old) = Element1 (new <$ old)
change new (Element2 old) = Element2 (new <$ old)
```

Or, you might define your type as a product, to generalize the function over the data constructors.

```
data MyTypeTags = Element1 | Element2
data MyType = MyType MyTypeTags (Maybe Int)

change :: Int -> MyType -> MyType
change new (MyType tag old) = MyType tag (new <$ old)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, if, for example, `a` had to have the type of `Int`, is there any way to work around that?

Comment: You could look at using the `MonoFunctor` class from the `mono-traversible` library. Otherwise, I believe you would just need to write your own function `change :: Int -> MyType -> MyType`, similar to `(<$)`, by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your data type using record syntax:

```
data MyType = Element1 { x :: (Maybe Int) } | Element2 { x :: (Maybe Int)}
instance1 = Element1 (Just 1)
instance2 = instance1 { x = Just 2 }
```